# Svg isn't rendered inside the Angular2 app

Tags: angular, svg

I've found that a simply pasted SVG inside an angular2 application isn't being rendered.

I have this code in index.html:

```
<body>
  <p>SVG outside the application:</p>
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
          style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
  </svg>
  <app>Loading...</app>

  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <script>
    System.import('bootstrap')
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e,
          'Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues');
      });
  </script>

</body>
```

and this simple code inside app.html:

```
<p>SVG inside the application:</p>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
        style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
</svg>
```

This example is built with angular2-seed application, and my question is:
What is the reason for problems rendering the **simple svg** (not directive, not some kind of interpolation etc) inside the application?
Is it an angular DOM manipulation problem or something else? And how can I fix it?

P.S. Of course, firstly, I planned to build an 'svg-icon' directive and use it to render different kinds of SVG icons using the type attribute. But the render failed and then I came up to this simple code.

Example you can see [here](http://punov.com/svg-render/) because unfortunately I can't yet build an angular2 example with fiddle or plunker.

Comment: [There's an open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4506) about it

Comment: My browser console shows the error System is not defined. Have you missed a js include somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

**`2.0.0-alpha.46 (2015-11-11)`** solved the problem (see [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/969b55326c8281a9e4a3d850ee7e368a276c9d13?short_path=4ac32a7#diff-4ac32a78649ca5bdd8e0ba38b7006a1e)). Since then it's working fine.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vpMSWrL9q5cs1IyB8eZC?p=preview).